# Coin toss problem, probability

Tags: probability

A coin has the property that the probability that it will land heads up when tosses $1$ time is $0.6$.
If the coin is to be tossed $3$ times, what is the probability that it will land heads up at least $2$ times.

Not quite know how to approach this question, especially I'm always bad at interpreting the probability of "at least" events.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: if $X$ is the number of heads, $P(X\geq2)=P(X=2)+P(X=3)$.

Answer (score 1):

In the present context, at least two times means that it will land heads up two or three times.

Since each trial is independent of the others, one has the probability:
\begin{align*}
p = 0.6\times 0.6\times 0.4 + 0.6\times 0.4\times 0.6 + 0.4\times 0.6\times 0.6 + 0.6\times 0.6\times 0.6 = 0.648
\end{align*}

If you want to formalize it further, you can think of $H_{j}$ as the event 'outcome equals head in th $j$-th trial' and $T_{j}$ as the event 'outcome equals tail in the $j$-th trial'. Moreover, if we assume independence, we are interested in the following probability:
\begin{align*}
p & = \mathbb{P}(H_{1}\cap H_{2}\cap T_{3}) + \mathbb{P}(H_{1}\cap T_{2}\cap H_{3}) + \mathbb{P}(T_{1}\cap H_{2}\cap H_{3}) + \mathbb{P}(H_{1}\cap H_{2}\cap H_{3})\\\\
& = \mathbb{P}(H_{1})\mathbb{P}(H_{2})\mathbb{P}(T_{3}) + \mathbb{P}(H_{1})\mathbb{P}(T_{2})\mathbb{P}(H_{3}) + \mathbb{P}(T_{1})\mathbb{P}(H_{2})\mathbb{P}(H_{3}) + \mathbb{P}(H_{1})\mathbb{P}(H_{2})\mathbb{P}(H_{3}) 
\end{align*}
which equals $0.648$ as previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First, the "at least" part can be interpreted as either the coin landing on head $2$ times or landing on head $3$ times so we should find both probabilities and add them together, we add them since it is Event 1 OR Event 2.

The probability of getting head $2$ times in $3$ tosses is the following:

$3C2*(0.6)^2*0.4=0.432$

Where $3C2$ means $3$ combination $2$, we use combination to account for the different places head can occur in, so for example one scenario would be getting the two heads in the first and third toss, another scenario would be getting it in the first and second toss, etc... The combination lets us take into account the different places. Also, we use $0.6^2$ as we need head twice and the probability of each one occurring is $0.6$ and we used $0.4$ once as getting two heads in three tosses means getting tail once and this happens with probability $0.4.$

Similarly, getting three heads in three tosses has probability:

$3C3*(0.6)=0.216$

Adding both probabilities we get $0.216+0.432=0.648$ which is the final answer.

I don't know which part of learning probability you are in and if you have learned about discrete probability distributions but what I used is called the binomial distribution (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), this distribution can be used when you have multiple Bernoulli trials, also known as a Bernoulli process (a Bernoulli trial is an event that has two possible outcomes only, either "success" or "failure", here we can consider getting head as success and getting tail as failure) and the trials have to be independent (so the probability of getting head is always the same) and when we need an "n" number of successes in "N" trials regardless at which attempts the successes come.